# Postgres partition size increase but no selectable data

Tags: postgresql, partition

I have a postgres table set up with a list partition defined on a column like so:

```
create table table1 (
 val varchar(10),
 t_type varchar(10)
) partition by list(t_type);
create table table1_xvals partition of table1 for values in ('xval1','xval2');
create table table1_yvals partition of table1 for values in ('yval1','yval2');
```

As I insert data into table1, and I can see the size of the table and individual partitions increasing, however when I try to select data from any of those tables, nothing shows up (select * from ). Is there anything wrong with how I'm creating the tables or selecting data?

Comment: I cannot replicate here. To your question add the answers to: 1) Postgres version 2) Your complete `INSERT` query 3) Your complete `SELECT` query

Comment: To my original comment I should have added: 4) How are you determining the size of the tables?

Comment: Manual inserts work as expected:
insert into table1 (val, t_type) values
('test1','xval1'),
('test2','xval2'),
('test3','yval1'),
('test4','yval2');
;

select * from table1;
select * from table1_xvals;
select * from table1_yvals;

The larger app is bulk inserting data with pandas to_sql - so maybe that's where the problem is. Testing that now

Comment: My money is on no `commit` being done at end of import.

Comment: re: table sizes - I'm looking at the table through dbeaver. Every couple seconds I'll hit refresh and the sizes of the table and the partitions go up

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. You are loading the data in a single database transaction, and the effects of a database transaction only become visible when the transaction is completed (committed). If you are loading the data with a single `INSERT` or `COPY` statement, the transaction will end as soon as the statement is done.